# Simulator files interaction: "The operation couldn't be completed. Invalid argument - Invalid argument"

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

When attempting to add files to the simulator I get the following error:

```
The operation couldn't be completed. Invalid argument

Invalid argument
```

[image]

When attempting to download a file via Safari and using share to save to files the UI does nothing, but the System logs yields:

```
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8496622D-825E-43EB-939E-04D9DDB548CB[72232] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.oneshot.0x10000000.SimulatorBridge[72268]): Service exited due to SIGABRT
```

Another SIGABRT happens when manually putting files into the simulators directory and attempting to open them. They do not generate preview. Not for text files, images or videos. I originally noticed it by not being able to open files in my app.

The system log mostly looks like this:

```
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8496622D-825E-43EB-939E-04D9DDB548CB[72232] (com.apple.intents.intents-helper): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8496622D-825E-43EB-939E-04D9DDB548CB[72232] (com.apple.intents.intents-helper): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8496622D-825E-43EB-939E-04D9DDB548CB[72232] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.SharingXPCHelper.73009): com.apple.photos.ImageConversionService (lint): XPC Service Info.plist is missing XPCService dictionary
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8496622D-825E-43EB-939E-04D9DDB548CB[72232] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.SharingXPCHelper.73009): com.apple.photos.VideoConversionService (lint): XPC Service Info.plist is missing XPCService dictionary
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8496622D-825E-43EB-939E-04D9DDB548CB[72232] (com.apple.textkit.nsattributedstringagent): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8496622D-825E-43EB-939E-04D9DDB548CB[72232] (com.apple.textkit.nsattributedstringagent): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8496622D-825E-43EB-939E-04D9DDB548CB[72232] (com.apple.uifoundation-bundle-helper): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8496622D-825E-43EB-939E-04D9DDB548CB[72232] (com.apple.uifoundation-bundle-helper): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8496622D-825E-43EB-939E-04D9DDB548CB[72232] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.SharingXPCHelper.73009): Failed to bootstrap path: path = /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaConversionService.framework/XPCServices/com.apple.photos.ImageConversionService.xpc, error = 107: Malformed bundle
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8496622D-825E-43EB-939E-04D9DDB548CB[72232] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.SharingXPCHelper.73009): Failed to bootstrap path: path = /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaConversionService.framework/XPCServices/com.apple.photos.VideoConversionService.xpc, error = 107: Malformed bundle
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8496622D-825E-43EB-939E-04D9DDB548CB[72232] (com.apple.AnnotationKit.MigratorService): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8496622D-825E-43EB-939E-04D9DDB548CB[72232] (com.apple.AnnotationKit.MigratorService): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit

[[A lot more "Unknown key for Boolean: Enable..." and some more errors for Image/Video Conversion]]
```

I've tried resetting the simulator, updating Xcode, and even completely wiping every Xcode related file with AppCleaner and reinstalling. It still occurs in every simulated device.

**EDIT**

I actually erased my entire computer and the issue is still occurring. What. Is. Going. On‽

**EDIT 2**: Digging deeper

I tried running the old open source [Textor](https://github.com/louisdh/textor) app, and when trying to create a document I get the similar error

(indented)

```
Textor[28964:966149] [DocumentManager]
Cannot create urlWrapper for url
    file:///Users/hans/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7EA9AEF5-F208-4BA1-8F61-F5F95CC15A47/data/Containers/Data/Application/A8736BA5-92DF-45A9-8622-CD312C68B403/tmp/Untitled.txt.
    error Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain
        Code=22
            "couldn't issue sandbox extension com.apple.app-sandbox.read-write 
            for '/Users/hans/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7EA9AEF5-F208-4BA1-8F61-F5F95CC15A47/data/Containers/Data/Application/A8736BA5-92DF-45A9-8622-CD312C68B403/tmp/Untitled.txt':
            Invalid argument"
        UserInfo={
            NSDescription=
               couldn't issue sandbox extension com.apple.app-sandbox.read-write for
               '/Users/hans/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7EA9AEF5-F208-4BA1-8F61-F5F95CC15A47/data/Containers/Data/Application/A8736BA5-92DF-45A9-8622-CD312C68B403/tmp/Untitled.txt':
               Invalid argument}.
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am still trying to find a solution.

Comment: This was related to a bigger issue related to a bug in simulator, which I think was fixed in a newer version of Xcode